# How to select random just one object?

Tags: python, 3d-view

"Select Random" selected by percent of visible objects, but how to select random just one object from visible?

Answer (score 1):

select > select random > f9

in the box set percent to >   (1/amount of object)*100

it will select 0 or 1 or 2 objects depending to seed
you can see how many got selected in the bottom right bar.